# How can i solve Error with insert into in php

Tags: php

```
$query = "Insert into $sql_table (date, Firstname, Lastname, StudentID, Score) values ('$date', '$Firstname', '$Lastname' , '$StudentID' , '$mark')";

            // execute the query
            $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
            if(!$result)
            {
                echo "<p>Error with " , $query , "</p>";
            }
            else
            {
                echo "<p>Table updated Successfully</p>";   
            }
```

Error with Insert into attempts (date, Firstname, Lastname, StudentID, Score) values ('2018-10-21 10:30:21pm', 'jhjsdhfhje', 'bnsdb' , '1023456789' , '6')

Comment: [Little Bobby](http://bobby-tables.com/) says ***[your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)***. Even [escaping the string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) is not safe! [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)

Answer (score -1):

Probably going to be that first parameter, but would depend on your table structure.

If `date` is a date column then MySQL will be expecting a "Y-m-d" formatted string, if it's a datetime then it will be expecting a "Y-m-d H:i:s".

My suggestion would be to drop the "pm" and see if that works.